# Oracle SQL loader Error while loading really huge log files

Tags: python, oracle, oracle10g, sql-loader, ora-03114

I have a python script which loops through log files in a directory and uses oracle sqlloader to load the log files to the oracle database. the script works properly and even the sqlloader..

But after loading around some 200k records,the loading fails with this exception..

```
Record 11457: Rejected - Error on table USAGE_DATA.
ORA-12571: TNS:packet writer failure

SQL*Loader-926: OCI error while uldlfca:OCIDirPathColArrayLoadStream for table USAGE_DATA
SQL*Loader-2026: the load was aborted because SQL Loader cannot continue.
Specify SKIP=11000 when continuing the load.
SQL*Loader-925: Error while uldlgs: OCIStmtExecute (ptc_hp)
ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE

SQL*Loader-925: Error while uldlgs: OCIStmtFetch (ptc_hp)
ORA-24338: statement handle not executed
```

I am not sure why this is hapenning.. I have checked the data files corresponding to the table's table space and it has auto extend set to true. What else could be the reason?

in the "**sqlldr**" command i have rows=1000 and Direct=True, so it commits for every 1000 records loaded, i have tested by varying this number, still getting same error.

```
sqlldr arisdw/arisdwabc01@APPDEV24 control=Temp_Sadish.ctl direct=true rows=1000 data=C:/_dev/logs/sample/data/mydata1.csv;
```

Comment: Are you sure it's actually committing every 1000 rows? I think it might just be generating a lot of data that will be loaded at once, and in the meantime the network is failing (eg: timing out)

Comment: Does it always fail at the same point? In other words, if you repeat this for the same input, will it fail at record 11457?

Comment: How many rows have you actually got loaded in USAGE_DATA?

Comment: by using direct path load, it was loading some 200k records and then throwing the above exception.. but i am not running the load with direct set to false and its working fine but very slow.. see my comment below in the answer

Comment: its not always at same point .. but roughly around the same file.. i don think there is issue with the file.. since it works for conventional load

Answer (score 0):

Post your controlfile contents.  What version of Oracle are you using?

The ORA-42338 error is the one I would focus on.  Are you doing any sort of data transformation in your job?  Calling functions or similar?

Comment: This is the control file  http://chopapp.com/#hma1v0zw . I am using Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - 64bi .. I am running the same script now but this time direct mode set to false.. and its loading now.. but taking ages. my issue is something similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435114/error-stopped-because-i-cant-continue-in-sqlloader-direct-mode .. but i guess the post says this is fixed in oracle 10